# EMU 8086 stores wrong array element value in register

Tags: assembly, masm, emu8086

```
.model small
.data
nizA db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8   
nizB db 8 dup(?)
len equ 8
.code   
main proc
mov si,0
mov di,0
mov cx,len

program: 
    mov al,nizA[si]      ;problem is here it always stores CDh in AL
    cbw                  ;convert AL to AX so i can divide
    mov bl,2             ;The number I want to divide so I test if its even or not
    div bl               ;Overflow message
    cmp ah,0
    je next:
        input:
            mov dl,nizA[si]
            mov nizB[di],dl
            inc di
next:
    add si,2
    loop program
endp
end
```

I  have this code here, for my finals that I need to make, very simple. Find odd numbers from even indexes of given array. So naturally it means I increase `SI` by 2 and I put that array element in `AL`. But no matter what number is in array, what gets stores in `AL` is always hex number CD, which then, if it was stored as it was supposed to, I want to do `CBW` to convert to `AX` and be able do divide with `BL`
I now just have error message from EMU 8086 saying

> divide error - overflow.  to manually process this error,  change
> address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.

Which surely is related to CD number, I only have two problems here

1. CD being stored instead of 1
2. Overflow (most likely because CD is way too high, but still I divide the numbers they only go less so it wont make sense kinda)

Comment: I've forgotten how EXE files work - do you have to load the data segment register yourself at program start?

Comment: No no, it does it automatically

Comment: Just because `0xCD` is the opcode of `INT`, which makes me wonder if you are getting your data from the code segment.

Comment: In listing table, I have as following
`[   5]    0000: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08               nizA db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

[   6]    0008: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               nizB db 8 dup(?)`
Kinda not clear looking, first is memory location, second it Machine code, third is source code
So I kinda assume that, it is being read good ?
Also in symbols table my two arrays are put in Data segment, I will see if IP points to the right places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "CD being stored instead of 1"

When a DOS .EXE starts, the `DS` segment register does **not** point at your program's .data section! The `DS` segment register points at the ProgramSegmentPrefix aka PSP. This 256-byte area is where DOS keeps some important data about the running program, and where you can retrieve the program's command line at offset address 128.

You found the value CDh when your code ran because that happens to be the very first byte in the PSP. It is the opcode for the `int 20h` instruction that always begins the PSP.

What you need to write is the following:

```
.code   
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
```

### "Overflow (most likely because CD is way too high, but still I divide the numbers they only go less so it wont make sense kinda)"

Actually it does make sense. Because you are using `CBW` to extend the dividend into `AX`, and because the value in `AL` erroneously is CDh, the new value in `AX` becomes FFCDh. When your code then divides this by 2 (using `mov bl, 2` `div bl`) the quotient is much larger than what can be stored in the division's dedicated quotient register `AL`. That's why you get the "divide error".

### Solutions

- Solution to verify that the division works this time:

```
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax
    mov  si, 0
    mov  di, 0
    mov  cx, len/2
program: 
    mov  al, nizA[si]
    mov  ah, 0           ; For UNSIGNED division don't use CBW
    mov  bl, 2
    div  bl
    cmp  ah, 0           ; Remainder
    je   next
    mov  dl, nizA[si]    ; Reload
    mov  nizB[di], dl
    inc  di
next:
    add  si, 2
    loop program
```

- Solution that avoids division in favor of `TEST` and adding some extra improvements too:

```
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax
    xor  si, si        ; Better than 'mov si, 0` for zeroing a register
    xor  di, di        ; idem
program: 
    mov  al, nizA[si]
    test al, 1
    jz   IsEven
    mov  nizB[di], al  ; Only storing 'odd' values
    inc  di
IsEven:
    add  si, 2         ; Next 'even' index
    cmp  si, len
    jb   program
```

See how `TEST AL, 1` is non-destructive on the `AL` register and that therefore you don't need to reload the value before writing to the *nizB* array?
Also note that you don't always need a separate loop counter. Here I have used the source array index instead.

Comment: Thank you very much man, this really explained everything and the code now works as required. I did not know I was supposed to load data, sometimes the code works nicely without loading it, so its interesting. For example if I would only to make input/output for the array without dividing and searching the numbers, the input from array `mov dl,niz[si] mov ah,2h`  would print out the good characters

Comment: @Завида Code that doesn't access memory can do without setting up the segment registers. And in the case that you describe of inputting into and directly outputting from the *niz* array, that seems to work fine (without having changed `DS`), because then the code will simply have overwritten the important stuff in the PSP. But if you overwrite enough of this PSP, you will see the program crash (not return to the OS).

Answer (score 1):

You load `cx` with `8`, so your loop will iterate 8 times.  But you increment `si` by 2 on every iteration, so after the first 4 iterations you are past the end of the `nizA` array.

Try replacing `mov cx, len` with `mov cx, len/2`.

By the way, a much simpler and more efficient way to check if `al` is odd is to do `test al, 1`, which sets flags according to the bitwise AND of `al` with 1.

Comment: After using that, no flags actually change, all flags are 0 since I begin the program and IF is always set to 1

Comment: Show the updated code, please.  I can't guess what you actually changed.

Comment: @Завида: But that would make sense, because all the even-numbered array elements actually are odd (so `test al, 1` will result in the zero flag being clear).

Comment: The code is actually the same, i just put `TEST AL,1` under `MOV AL,nizA[si]` and I let the code run by single step , I tried now to to `TEST AL,2` and `ZF` actually was set to 1, so that is really weird, because the `AL` register is still saying `CD`

Comment: I mean, if `AL` doesn't contain the value 1 the first time you pass `MOV AL, nizA[si]` then something is wrong before we even get to the loop counter or the `TEST`.  I think we're back to the question of whether your code is being built and loaded correctly, so that `DS:nizA` actually points to your array.  Unfortunately I don't know much about how EMU8086 does things, but it might help others if you would completely describe your process of building and running your code.

Comment: Also, after using `cbw` which should just make `AL` into `AX,` I get even stranger number, `AH` gets FF while `AL` remains CD , FFCD is 65485 in decimal, so I do not know what happens really

Comment: @Завида. Note that `TEST AL, 2` should set the zero flag when `AL = 0CDh`, because `0CDh and 2` is 0.  It should also set the zero flag with `AL = 1` for the same reason.  So nothing's weird about that - what's weird is that AL contains `0CDh` in the first place.  Forget about everything past that point, you need to fix that first.

Comment: @Завида: The result for CBW is also normal.  Read the description of CBW: it sign-extends, so AH gets filled with a copy of the sign bit of AL.  Now the sign bit of 0CDh is set (it represents a negative signed 8-bit number) so AH gets set to all 1s, i.e. FF.  That way AX contains the appropriate negative signed 16-bit number; they are both the signed number -51.  Again, this is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Well I do not have process of building the code, because EMU 8086 you just need to click emulate and it will do all of that for you. emu does the first run on its own, and you just watch him do step by step as you have access to stack memories tables...  I honestly do not know how to test if this is pointing to my array or where it does, I do not know that much yet

Comment: Okay, so you are pasting that exact code into EMU8086 and clicking "emulate"?  Then I think it is an EMU8086-specific issue that I can't help with, sorry.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for helping me, do you then have a nice software that you can recommend to me as replacement for EMU?

Comment: @Завида: Dosbox is a better emulator if you need DOS emulation, Bochs if you just need BIOS or bare-metal.  EMU8086 is ancient and buggy.